# How can I serialize a Java object that has one member which is a json string

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Pojo that contains one member `displayPropsJson`which is a clientside json string. It is validated with a JSON schema before storing on the server. 
i.e.

```
public class Item {
    Long id; //23
    String name; //"itemsName"
    String displayPropsJson; // "{\"bold\" : true, \"htmlAllowed\" : true, \"icon\" :\"star.jpg\" }"
}
```

I'd like the serialized version of this to output the displayPropsJson as displayProps sub object for example:

```
{
   "id" :23,
   "name: : "itemsName",
   "displayProps" : {
         "bold" : true,
         "htmlAllowed" : true,
         "icon" : "star.jpg"
    }
```

}

How can I do this with a Jackson serializer that outputs elements and the json string as json?
The displayPropsJson will vary but is always valid json.

Comment: This is an interesting one. For sure you can have a jackson serializer and print the value of displayProps as json, but I am curious if the deserializer would be able to handle it. Could you please update the question with your findings?

Comment: Construct the JSON tree, then edit to replace displayPropsJson with it's tree.  Then serialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider two options apart of creating a custom serializer.

- Use the `@JsonRawString` annotation to mark a String field that
  should be serialized as is without quoting of characters.
- Make the `ObjectMapper` available inside your object instance ([consider value injection](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureValueInjection)) and provide a getter method that returns `JsonNode` deserialized from your json string value.

Here is an example demonstrating both:

```
public class JacksonRawString {
    public static class Item {
        final private ObjectMapper mapper;

        public Long id = 23l;
        public String name = "itemsName";
        @JsonRawValue
        public String displayPropsJson = "{\"bold\" : true, \"htmlAllowed\" : true, " +
            "\"icon\" :\"star.jpg\" }";

        public JsonNode getDisplayPropsJson2() throws IOException {
            return mapper.readTree(displayPropsJson);
        }

        public Item(ObjectMapper mapper) {
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(
                mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(new Item(mapper)));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "id" : 23,
  "name" : "itemsName",
  "displayPropsJson" : {"bold" : true, "htmlAllowed" : true, "icon" :"star.jpg" },
  "displayPropsJson2" : {
    "bold" : true,
    "htmlAllowed" : true,
    "icon" : "star.jpg"
  }
}
```

Note that the `displayPropsJson2` get pretty output since it was serialized as `JsonNode`

Comment: Thanks Alexey I went with the @JsonRawString. 
One extra constraint on the implementation is the object also needs to be Serializable to persist. the JsonNode class is itself not serializable. Is there another annotation I can use will support this in/out.

Comment: @claya You should be able to  make  Item class Serializable as long as you mark ObjectMapper field 'transient'. Why JsonNode needs to be serialisable if there is no such a field in the class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am sure this can be done with custom Jackson serializer. Another thing you could do is implement JsonSerializable, 
}

Yet another possibility is to implement the [JsonSerializable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/apirefs.111230/e27204/oracle/adfmf/framework/api/JSONSerializable.html)

A final possibility would be to switch libraries and use [Google's GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), which makes it easy to serialize objects into and out of json.